# Clarification re version coordination with Azure DevOps pipeline triggers

Tags: azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, I have a build pipeline B and a deployment pipeline D. (These are YAML pipelines.) Pipeline D has two stages, one for deploying to the Dev server immediately, the other for deploying to the Test server upon approval. Pipeline B is triggered, through a CI trigger, by commits (via pull request) to the main branch in the repo. Pipeline D is triggered, through a pipeline trigger, by successful completion of Pipeline B.

Pipeline B is configured to build the latest version from the main branch. Of course, I want Pipeline D to be deploying the build that was created by Pipeline B. This is especially true when the Test deployment begins once it's been approved, which could be a day or two later. Even if there have been intervening commits and builds, I want this deployment to be based on this build.

Microsoft seems to guarantee this, writing, at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml, "If the triggering pipeline and the triggered pipeline use the same repository, both pipelines will run using the same commit when one triggers the other. This is helpful if your first pipeline builds the code and the second pipeline tests it."

But here, more or less, is code from my Pipeline D:

```
deploy:
  steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      displayName: 'Download artifacts from build'
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: '19be1886-bedf-4a25-b77b-3a427a7ca358'
        pipeline: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
        specificBuildWithTriggering: true
        buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
        downloadType: 'specific'
        itemPattern: 'drop/**'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: Kubernetes@0
      displayName: 'Deploy configuration to k8s'
      inputs:
        kubernetesServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceConnection }}'
        namespace: '$(kubernetesNamespace)'
        command: apply
        useConfigurationFile: true
        configuration: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/$(kubernetesConfigurationFile)'
```

This seems to be declaring the build to use: the latest one. This contradicts what Microsoft's doc seems to have indicated. If it's a matter of changing it here from "latest" to something else, what do I change it to so that the deployment is from the same build that triggered Pipeline D to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirement, you need to make Deployment Pipeline D use pipeline B's corresponding build artifacts instead of downloading the latest one.

Since the Pipeline D is triggered by Pipeline B, you can use the Pipeline variable: `$(BUILD.TRIGGEREDBY.BUILDID)`.It can get the buildID that triggers the pipeline.

You can use the variable in DownloadBuildArtifacts task.

For example:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download artifacts from build'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '19be1886-bedf-4a25-b77b-3a427a7ca358'
    pipeline: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
    specificBuildWithTriggering: true
    buildVersionToDownload: specific
    buildId: '$(BUILD.TRIGGEREDBY.BUILDID)'
    itemPattern: 'drop/**'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Comment: Thank you! But--did you mean to have buildVersionToDownload twice and remove downloadType? I'm thinking you might have intended buildVersionToDownload: 'specific' AND downloadType: 'specific'.

Comment: Sorry My fault. Only use specific will meet your requirement. I have edit my answer.

Comment: So, *not* `downloadType`? Also--one more question--my pipeline sets up parameters for a pipeline template, `- template: ...`: Do the steps in the pipeline template have access to the Build variables for the pipeline that includes it?

Comment: Well, I tried it, and they do, apparently, have that access.